# Central Admin UI no longer working at all

Tags: 2010, administration, central-administration

I have sharePoint 2010 installed in a dev environment.  I am a developer who is reasonably new to SP.

All of a sudden central admin no longer works up until yesterday I was getting there using:

```
http://dev-sharepoint.dev.local:9999/
```

When I browse here now I am faced with this:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5 Date: Wed, 18 Sep 2013
>   04:03:29 GMT Connection: close

There is nothing in the ULS logs at all.  I have spent the last few hours researching however without a clear ULS log entry or a clear browser error I am a bit stuck.  here is what I have done:

1. run the product configuration wizard.  note - I did not disconnect from the server farm and I said no this machine will continue to host the web site.  It goes through 9 of 9 steps with success and then open a browser at this URL:

   ..._`admin/adminconfigintro.aspx?scenarioid=adminconfig& welcomestringid=farmconfigurationwizard_welcome`

   but shows this:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  Troubleshoot
>   issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.  Correlation ID:
>   b473c2e3-8b67-4a84-a2d0-ac374b2bbd69  Date and Time: 9/18/2013 2:40:45
>   PM

when I go into ULS viewer and look at the correlationtree it show this:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPRibbon..ctor()
>   at ASP._admin_admin_master._*BuildControl*_control30()      at
>   ASP._admin_admin_master._*BuildControl*_control21()      at
>   ASP._admin_admin_master._*BuildControl*_control2()      at
>   ASP._admin_admin_master.__BuildControlTree(_admin_admin_master __ctrl)
>   at System.Web.UI.MasterPage.CreateMaster(TemplateControl owner,
>   HttpContext context, VirtualPath masterPageFile, IDictionary
>   contentTemplateCollection)      at System.Web.UI.Page.get_Master()
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ApplyMasterPage()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit()      at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

1. Next I  read about provisioning so I ran this:

   ```
   psconfig.exe -cmd adminvs -unprovision
   ```

   and then this:

   ```
   psconfig.exe -cmd adminvs provision -port 8888 -windowsauthprovider onlyusentlm
   ```

   All three steps for both commands ran with success

But I still have no central admin.  I ran the product configuration wizard again after the re-provisioning however I get the same result.  I have no idea what to do, Help...

The only major thing I did yesterday was to delete two web applications.  They were both failed attempts at configuring mySite.  I am unsure what I did wrong.  I followed these steps  [http://sharepointgeorge.com/2010/configuring-my-site-sharepoint-2010/][1] which look very through however after completion I was getting a website can not be displayed when I tried to browse to the profile and the mySite.

I have also recycled both the central admin and the web services root app pools

Editing - adding solution - Apparently this error:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5 Date: Wed, 18 Sep 2013
```

means there the web application can not find the site collection.  Commonly found if you try to browse to a web application before a site collection is created.

So After hours and hours of research the very last thing I tried was to  detach and re-attach the content database.  The problem was this did not work:

```
Dismount-SPContentDatabase "SharePoint_AdminContent_be612b9b-749d-4e20-b5a7-f14aa0c5fd90"
```

It is thought that its becasue the content database is attached to an SPAdministrationWebApplication web application rather than  a normal SPWebApplication. so this did work:

```
get-spcontentdatabase -webapplication http://siteaddress | dismount-SPcontentdatabase
```

Then to re-attach:

```
Mount-SPContentdatabase -name SharePoint_AdminContent_be612b9b-749d-4e20-b5a7-f14aa0c5fd90 -DatabaseServer DEV-SQL01-VM   -Webapplication http://siteaddress
```

After this every thigs is back to normal.  I still do not know how the occurred

Answer (score 1):

I faced that problem earlier.

In my case first i tried to stop and restart User profile Service and User Profile Sync service, then (restart didn't helped) deleted User Profile Service and re-created it.

Comment: Thank you for you time and advice however I had actually removed the user profile service.  I did this because the mySite web application was what I was referring to in the 'The only major thing I did' ....this was the web application that was removed.  All this said I ahve a solution.  See the edit in the original post